# How can I bind a key-event to a Python tkinter canvas item?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, key-bindings

I want to bind a key event to a Python tkinter canvas item, for example to a rectangle. I am able to bind a key to the canvas itself (see example code, key "a", "b", "c"), but not to a canvas-item as a rectangle (see example code, key "r", "s", "t"). What am I doing wrong?

I tried it in this way, but I get only a reaction, when "a", "b" or "c" is pressed at any place in the canvas, but never when "r", "s" or "t" is pressed over the rectangle:

```
import tkinter as tk

def canvas_hit(event):
    print("Canvas Hit")

def rectangle_hit(event):
    print("Rectangle Hit")

root = tk.Tk()

canvas_id = tk.Canvas(root, height=100, width=200)
rectangle = canvas_id.create_rectangle(20,20,50,50, fill="red")
canvas_id.grid()

canvas_id.bind_all("a"           , canvas_hit)
canvas_id.bind_all("<b>"         , canvas_hit)
canvas_id.bind_all("<KeyPress-c>", canvas_hit)
canvas_id.tag_bind(rectangle, "r"           , rectangle_hit)
canvas_id.tag_bind(rectangle, "<s>"         , rectangle_hit)
canvas_id.tag_bind(rectangle, "<KeyPress-t>", rectangle_hit)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to bind keyboard events to canvas objects, except for text items. From the canonical documentation for the `focus` method of the canvas:

*"Set the keyboard focus for the canvas widget to the item given by tagOrId. If tagOrId refers to several items, then the focus is set to the first such item in the display list that supports the insertion cursor. If tagOrId does not refer to any items, **or if none of them support the insertion cursor, then the focus is not changed.***"

The only canvas item that supports the insertion cursor is text.

The most common solution is to bind to the canvas (*not* using `bind_all` but to the actual canvas), and then also giving the canvas the keyboard focus.

```
canvas_id.bind("r", rectangle_hit)
canvas.focus_set()
```

It is then up to you to decide which canvas item should receive the event. For example, you can use the tag `"current"` to reference the object under the cursor. Or, you could implement your own concept of focus for a canvas object.

Comment: Also make sure the item and canvas is not disabled.

Comment: Can you please explain, why bind_all shall not be used (it worked in my example code)?

Comment: @MatthiasSchweikart you can use bind_all but that does exactly what it says. If the focus is on some other widget such as an entry or text widget it will still fire. If you only want the event to be caught when the canvas has focus then you need to bind on the widget.